# Should I turn iCloud Photos off before resetting iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app

If iCloud photos is turn on, any addition or deletion of photos in the iPhone is reflected in iCloud. So, since I'm resetting the iPhone, which will delete all the photos on it, should I turn off iCloud photos so that my photos on iCloud remain intact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need, when you reset the phone it will of course reset the phone, but it doesn't delete everything remotely.

So long as you've ensured all your photos have synced, you should just click the reset all content & settings option. It will ask you to sign out of iCloud to disable Activation Lock and then it'll reset the device. Your photos will remain in iCloud.

Answer (score -1):

iCloud is not based on phones, but on iCloud accounts. You are removing the iCloud account *from your phone* when you reset your phone. You don't change the account. So nothing will happen do the data in iCloud.